# ColdFusion Array - storing form data in array

Tags: arrays, forms, struct, coldfusion

I have a simple form that stores name, email and message. When it is submitted I am storing the 3 fields in a 2D array and each additional time I submit the form I want to add that data to what has already been submitted.

However each time I submit the form, rather than creating a new element in the array, it is overwriting what was previously submitted.

In my Application.cfc I'm declaring my array as follows:

```
<cffunction name="onApplicationStart">
    <!--- Define array that will store form submissions --->
    <cfset Application.formSubmissions = ArrayNew(2) />
</cffunction>
```

And my test.cfm page has the main code:

```
<cfscript>
// if form submitted
if (StructKeyExists(Form,"name") AND Form.name NEQ "") {
    // define constants for column names
    Variables.name = 1;
    Variables.email = 2;
    Variables.message = 3;
    // define array position
    Variables.arrayLen = ArrayLen(Application.formSubmissions);
    Variables.arrayPos = Variables.arrayLen + 1;
    // add form data to array
    Application.formSubmissions[Variables.arrayPos][Variables.name] = Form.name;
    Application.formSubmissions[Variables.arrayPos][Variables.email] = Form.email;
    Application.formSubmissions[Variables.arrayPos][Variables.message] = Form.message;
    // reset form fields to stop insert
    Form.name = "";
    Form.email = "";
    Form.message = "";
}
</cfscript>
<cfdump var="#Application.formSubmissions#">
<cfoutput>

<form action="##" method="post" name="contactForm" id="contactForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label name="nameLabel" for="name">Name</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label name="emailLabel" for="email">Email</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label name="emailLabel" for="email">Message</label></td>
            <td><textarea name="message" id="message" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submitBtn" id="submitBtn" value="SUBMIT" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>

</cfoutput>
```

Can someone point out where I seem to be going wrong please?

Comment: This looks like a risky way to store data.  Applications could be restarted without your knowledge for a variety of reasons.

Comment: Just a coupla observations here. The application scope is not the correct approach here. What if more than one person on the site is filling out the form at the same time? You should perhaps be using the session scope, and have a subkey within that for form name, within that an array of form completions. Secondly, an array of arrays is seldom the right data structure for anything you'll be doing in CFML. What you're trying to do here looks more like an array of structs. Each array element is the instance of the completed for (even just a copy of the form scope would do it).

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me. I suspect your `onApplicationStart` event is fired on every request.

To make sure it's not the redefinition of your `Application.formSubmissions`, remove the line `<cfset Application.formSubmissions = ArrayNew(2) />` in your `onApplicationStart` function and replace the `<cfscript>` part of your example with the following code:

```
<cfscript>

    if ( !structIsEmpty(Form) ) {

        if (
            ( structKeyExists(Form, "name") && len(trim(Form.name)) ) &&
            ( structKeyExists(Form, "email") && len(trim(Form.email)) ) &&
            ( structKeyExists(Form, "name") && len(trim(Form.name)) )
        ) {

            if ( !structKeyExists(Application, "formSubmissions") ) {
                Application.formSubmissions = [];
            }

            Application.formSubmissions.add([
                trim(Form.name),
                trim(Form.email),
                trim(Form.message)
            ]);
        }

    }

</cfscript>
```

This will initialize `Application.formSubmissions` the lazy way and prevent recreation. *Note: This is for testing purpose only as the Application scope should be locked to avoid race conditions. You should add the Form validation regardless.*

Answer (score 0):

Use struct, is better and easier to understand.

```
<cffunction name="onApplicationStart">
    <!--- Define array that will store form submissions --->
    <cfset Application.formSubmissions = ArrayNew(1) />
</cffunction>
<cfscript>
    Application.formSubmissions[Variables.arrayPos] = StrunctNew();
    Application.formSubmissions[Variables.arrayPos].name = Form.name;
    Application.formSubmissions[Variables.arrayPos].email  = Form.email;
    Application.formSubmissions[Variables.arrayPos].message  = Form.message;
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

One more tip:

Use CompareNoCase to compare strings. It is faster than EQ/NEQ. See the information below.

CompareNoCase

Description: Performs a case-insensitive comparison of two strings.

Returns: An indicator of the difference:

A negative number, if string1 is less than string2 0, if string1 is equal to string2 A positive number, if string1 is greater than string2

Function syntax:

```
CompareNoCase(Form.name, "")
```

If the above returns 0, the form variable is empty.

More datails in [ColdFusion Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f83.html)